# Linq is querying the right table in the wrong schema

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I set my default schema to "WHE" in my override of the OnModelCreating function:

```
modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("WHE");
```

I created a table through the CodeFirst Entity Framework:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Exemptions.Models
{
    public class KillYears
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Year { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is the code from the Migration:

```
public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "WHE.KillYears",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Year = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

    }
```

Here is the table in the database after running Update-Database:

[Table in the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDgjS.jpg)

Here is the call to the model:

```
(from k in model.KillYears
 orderby k.Year descending
 where k.Year != null
 select k).ToList()
```

...and here is the error I am getting:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: 'An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.'
>   Inner Exception
>   SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.KillYears'.

I searched for "dbo." in my solution, and got this result:

```
Find all "dbo.", Find Results 1, Entire Solution, ""
  Matching lines: 0    Matching files: 0    Total files searched: 472
```

Can anyone tell me why my linq query is looking at the wrong schema?  I've created 8 or 9 tables in this project since I took it over, and none of them have had this problem.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: The problem was found based off of the question @Orwel asked.  The person who built this application originally has two Models, [appname]Model and IdentityModels.  HasDefaultSchema was set in one model, but not the other.  I called HasDefaultSchema in the second model and it solved the problem.

Comment: Are you sure the method HasDefaultSchema is called?

Comment: @Orwel see my edit for the answer.  It's stupid.  You were right, but it's still stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code sould work. Are you sure the method HasDefaultSchema is called? If your context inherit from base context, you need call base.OnModelCreating :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    ...
}
```